# Rank columns independently

Tags: r, rank

I am new to R and trying to rank the columns independently using ties='first'.  When I run the rank function it doesn't do each column independently.  How would I do that?[Script Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kURBi.png)

```
mat <- matrix(c(10,5,15,4,3,200,150,4,75,80,25,30,16,57,15,45),ncol=4)
mat

rank(mat,ties='first')
```

Comment: Do you want something like: `apply(mat, 2, rank, ties='first')` ?

Comment: @GKi Thank you, that works!

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
mat <- matrix(c(10,5,15,4,3,200,150,4,75,80,25,30,16,57,15,45),ncol=4)

apply(mat, MARGIN=2, FUN=rank, ties="first")
```

`apply` is an extremely useful function to know in R. It, well, *applies* the function `FUN` to each row (`MARGIN=1`) and/or column (`MARGIN=2`) of a matrix or matrix-like object.