# Elegant way to obtain order(rank) of each column of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, apply, rank

I want each element of each column of a matrix to be ranked like one will rank a vector. For instance given that `A` is a matrix as defined below.

```
(A = matrix(c(36, 37, 33, 38, 36, 32), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE))
```

How do I tell `R` to get the rank of each column in the matrix `A` as shown below?

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]   36   37
[2,]   33   38
[3,]   36   32
```

The rank or order is

```
(rank_A = matrix(c(2.5, 2, 1, 3, 2.5, 1), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE))

      [,1] [,2]
[1,]  2.5    2
[2,]  1.0    3
[3,]  2.5    1
```

I could have written it as below.

```
(rank_A <- matrix(rank(A[ ,1]), rank(A[ ,2]), nrow = 3, byrow = FALSE))
```

which will give me what I want but I wan a elegant way of doing it.

Comment: [Rank columns independently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64429230/rank-columns-independently)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can try this

```
> apply(A, 2, rank)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  2.5    2
[2,]  1.0    3
[3,]  2.5    1
```

Answer (score 2):

We may use `colRanks` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
t(colRanks(A, ties.method = 'average'))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  2.5    2
[2,]  1.0    3
[3,]  2.5    1
```

---

Or using `dapply` and `frank`

```
library(collapse)
library(data.table)
dapply(A, MARGIN = 2, FUN = frank)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  2.5    2
[2,]  1.0    3
[3,]  2.5    1
```

Comment: Your solution is great just like the other is just that I have to make a choice.

Comment: @DanielJames if you are looking for elegance vs efficiency, apply is more compact.  With regards to efficiency, may be `dapply` would be faster